# Inconsistent, but frequent EXC_BAD_ACCESS access with sqlite3_step(statement)

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios5, exc-bad-access

I am getting frequent EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes in iOS while executing this line:

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

}
```

Its used to deliver results in my `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  function.

Any ideas? The SQL etc looks fine, and the database is being updated in a background thread, after which I call the foreground thread to update UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you database is being updated in the background and you're accessing it in the foreground thread I'd highly recommend to use some kind of blocking mechanism to prevent race situation. I don't think sqlite is thread safe.

Comment: For the record, that fixed it :-)